# android animate views inside a scroll view while scrolling

Tags: android, android-animation

Is there example android code or sample android app which demonstrate animation of the views while scrolling.

For example. In a scroll view some items are not visible when you scroll the items will start to come inside the screen that time i just want to animate that view.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have you got any solution @Navin

Answer (score 1):

Download [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos&hl=en) app. Here you will find **tons of libraries** of your use. I also seen the library which your are asking in this app. You will find **source code links** in the app as well.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos&hl=en

Or You can do one more thing

Just add on scroll listener and some more listeners are there by which you can detect which portion of your scroll view is visible.

Then You can add animation to those views.

Comment: Thank you. will have a look at it.

Comment: Lots of open source demo libraries are there for your use. See the edit for more.

Answer (score 0):

Try Listview animation library.
Modify it and use.

https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

Comment: I need to work with Horizontal Scroll View. anyway thank you.